# open_basedir error preventing avatar uploads

Tags: php, open-basedir

I'm getting this error when avatars are being uploaded on my site.  I've changed "open_basedir = /home/" to "open_basedir =" in my php.ini on my server.  It's a dedicated server and I rebooted it after making the adjustment.

```
Warning: is_writable() [function.is-writable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/source:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/source/public_html/lib/php/tru/directory.php on line 46



Warning: is_writable() [function.is-writable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/source:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/source/public_html/lib/php/tru/directory.php on line 46
```

What else can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check you only have one php.ini file? No need to reboot, just restart apache with apachectl restart http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/apache/restart-apache/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with open_basedir, it is in your image upload. Look closely at the error message:

```
File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):
```

I bet there is an empty variable where the file name/path should be.